# Get mongoose models from external file

Tags: node.js, mongoose, schema

I would like to import a model from an external file and then write an entry into my mongoDB, but something is wrong. The entry is not written...

models.js:

```
    module.exports = function(mongoose) {

    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var product_rating = new Schema ({

        id: Number,
        product_id: Number,
        rate: Number,
        description: String }, {collection:'product_rating'});

    var models = {

        product_ratings : mongoose.model('product_ratings', product_rating)

    };

    return models;

};
```

server.js:

```
//some standard express code...

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var models = require('./app/models/models.js')(mongoose);

    //mongo connection...
     var db =...


    var rating = new models.product_ratings({

        id: 1,
        product_id: 5,
        rate: 3,
        description: 'A great product!'

});

rating.save(function(err){

    if (err) {console.log(err);}
    else {console.log(rating);}

});
```

I think the problem is that the model does not refer to the db - how can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Hucho

Comment: Strange, but your code works. `findOne` finds new product. I've only changed to `require('./models.js')(mongoose)`. That doesn't matter. How do you understand that the entry is not written?

Comment: Test your codes, the data is saved in the `product_rating` collection, with data `{ "_id" : ObjectId("56f0ba15ef1783d02dbee1f1"), "id" : 1, "product_id" : 5, "rate" : 3, "description" : "A great product!", "__v" : 0 }`

Comment: If I use mongoose. connect...it works. If i Use var db = mongoose.createconnection(); it does not? Somehow, the save function seems not to know about the connection. Do I have to inject the db variable somehow?